# How to get result for count from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have two tables, `Cars` and `Defect`. I'm maintaining relation by passing `car_id` to defect table as foreign key.

I've 3000 records in cars table and 16K records in defect tables (having `open_defect` and `close_defect`). I'm trying to find out all Cars(3000) with count of open defects (if there is no any open defect against car should return 0).

I'm trying some queries:

```
SELECT cars.cars_id_primary ,IF(COUNT(defect.defect_id_primary)>0,1,0) AS `def_count`
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN defect ON cars.cars_id_primary = defect.cars_id AND defect.defect_status_id =1
WHERE cars.stage_id !=5 
GROUP BY cars.cars_id_primary
ORDER BY cars.updated_on
```

This query gives me result but takes too much time to execute.
Need to optimize this query. I'm stuck to optimize.

Any help welcomes, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about performance should include table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`) structures for every table involved in the SQL query and also a `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: Do you want columns from cars table inside select clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to involve cars table inside `GROUP BY`. Rewrite your query like so:

```
SELECT cars.cars_id_primary, COALESCE(agg.open_defect_count, 0) AS open_defect_count
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cars_id, COUNT(*) AS open_defect_count
    FROM defect
    WHERE defect_status_id = 1
    GROUP BY cars_id
) AS agg ON cars.cars_id_primary = agg.cars_id
WHERE cars.stage_id != 5 
ORDER BY cars.updated_on
```

You will need to create indexes as well. I suggest starting with `ix_defect(defect_status_id, cars_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the performance by using indexes. Can you create an index on `cars_id_primary` of `cars` table and index on `cars_id` of `defect` like below sql. Then you can try your query.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON cars (cars_id_primary);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON defect (cars_id);
```

Comment: "You can increase the performance by using indexes" Not always in fact it's misleading a optimizer might **choose** not to use a index and choose a table scan over a index "scan"

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question, I made a little bit changes in  your query,

```
SELECT cars.cars_id_primary ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (defect.defect_id_primary)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END) AS `def_count`
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN defect ON cars.cars_id_primary = defect.cars_id 
WHERE cars.stage_id !=5 AND defect.defect_status_id =1 
GROUP BY cars.cars_id_primary
ORDER BY cars.updated_on
```

try this